# Flex: Validator on RadioButtonGroup

Tags: apache-flex, validation, radio-button

I have a Validator on a RadioButtonGroup of 2 Radios.  There's a checkbox above the RadioButtonGroup whereby if `checkbox.Selected`, then the Radios are enabled.
So the Validator is required if the `checkbox.Selected`.  So far so good.

The problem is once a `radio` gets selected, the RadioButtonGroup selectedValue gets set.  When I uncheck the checkbox I set the radios to not selected, but the selectedValue on the  RadioButtonGroup doesn't get reset -- it hold the previous value.  I tried setting it to null but no luck.

Therefore if I check the checkbox again and submit, the Validator see a selectedValue on the RadioButtonGroup.  Even though none of the radios are selected, validation passes.

How can I reset the RadioButtonGroup to its initial state when I uncheck the CheckBox?
Thanks.

---

PS
I looked at the underlying code for `RadioButtonGroup.selectedValue = null`, and what it does is look for a radio in the with the parameter value.  If it doesn't find it nothing gets set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does RadioButtonGroup.selection have the same problem? If not, I'd suggest using that instead.